# Variable was not declared in scope when declared in header

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of making a Tic Tac Toe game in C++. I declared this variable (slot1) in the Header and in the cpp I tried to use this variable, yet it says "error: 'slot1' was not declared in this scope".

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TicTacToe.h"

using namespace std;

TicTacToe gameOn;

int main()
{
    gameOn.startGame();
    return 0;
}





//TicTacToe.h
#ifndef TICTACTOE_H
#define TICTACTOE_H


class TicTacToe
{
    public:
        void startGame();
        void setupGame();

        //As you can see slot1 is clearly declared
        char s1ot1 = '1'; char slot2 = '2'; char slot3 = '3';
        char slot4 = '4'; char slot5 = '5'; char slot6 = '6';
        char slot7 = '7'; char slot8 = '8'; char slot9 = '9';

};

#endif // TICTACTOE_H





//TicTacToe.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToe.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string mode;

void TicTacToe::startGame()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "This is a Tic Tac Toe game \n This game needs 2 players" << endl;
    while(true){
        cout << "Will you play? (Yes/No)" << endl;
        cin >> mode;
        if(mode == "Yes"){
            break;
        }else if(mode == "No"){
            cout << "Thank you for choosing this game..." << endl;
            exit(0);
            break;
        }else{
            cout << "Your input is invalid" << endl;
        }
    }
    setupGame();
}

void TicTacToe::setupGame(){
    cout << slot1 << " | " << slot2 << " | " << slot3 << endl; //slot1 variable "was not declared"
    cout << "----------------------" << endl;
    cout << slot4 << " | " << slot5 << " | " << slot6 << endl;
    cout << "----------------------" << endl;
    cout << slot7 << " | " << slot8 << " | " << slot9 << endl;
}
```

I changed the data type and ran fine, yet the problem is that specific variable, because if I remove it completely, the other chars are accepted normally, when they are written exactly the same as slot1. What's wrong with my code?

I'm new to C++, please be specific as possible.

Comment: typo.  slot1 != s1ot1

Comment: You never declared a variable named `slot1`. You did declare a variable named `s1ot1`, but aren't using it.

Comment: This reminds me of when I spend hours tracking down "complicated" linker errors related to complicated cross-platform calling conventions and exports, only to realize the unresolved external function is not implemented anywhere.  At all.

Comment: ` //As you can see slot1 is clearly declared` - or not

Comment: OK gang. Stop with the slot shaming.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `s1ot1` not `slot1` (notice the 1("one") instead of the "l"):

```
char s1ot1 = '1';
```

change to

```
char slot1 = '1';
```

Comment: Yeah I figured... I fell kinda stupid now... Thanks anyway :)